# Logcat printing "interface name: null" during each DefaultHttpClient execution method call

Tags: android, httpclient, httpresponse, logcat, http-get

I am contacting a web service multiple times to get a JSON String via `HttpGet` and `DefaultHttpClient`.

```
...
DefaultHttpClient defaultHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse httpResponse = (HttpResponse)defaultHttpClient.execute(httpGet);
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
...
```

I find that LogCat is printing **interface name: null** with tag **System.out** for each time `HttpResponse httpResponse = (HttpResponse)defaultHttpClient.execute(httpGet);` is executed.

Am i establishing this http connection properly with `HttpGet`? Is there a different way?

How can i create this connection and not get **interface name: null** LogCat messages from the **System.out** tag?

Comment: I am also having same problem on Galaxy S but when I use Nexus or HTC Desire, then it stops showing this interface null message. might be some problem with Samsung Galaxy S

Comment: ha, i am also using the galaxy s.  i never thought to try on another device

Comment: I can confirm that I see it on a Galaxy S (Fascinate) but not on a Nexus S

Comment: Aaand I get this on Galaxy S Vibrant but nowhere else.

Comment: Maybe this depends on the specific android version of the device?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the DefaultHTTPClient Asynchronously? I had a similar error in the past (Android 2.x) and found once I made a singleton for the DefaultHTTPClient and put my web request inside an AsyncTask this error went away.

Answer (score 0):

Use these;

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
```